# LINQ-to-XML Error "is not a member of 'String'"

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

The following code returns the error from the For Each loop. I have similar code that does not return the error.

**'DisplayTitle' is not a member of 'Sting'**

```
Dim evXML As XDocument = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/event.xml"))

Dim sbEventDetail As New StringBuilder()
Dim summary = _
From sum In evXML.<root>.Elements() _
Select sum...<DisplayTitle>.Value

For Each item In summary
    sbEventDetail.Append("<h4>" & item.DisplayTitle & "</h4>")
Next
```

The XML:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <StartTime>2010-03-05T16:00:00</StartTime>
  <EndTime>2010-03-06T02:00:00</EndTime>
  <Duration>10:00:00</Duration>
  <DisplayTitle>MARCH MADNESS</DisplayTitle>
  <Location>565 Main St</Location>
  <IsAllDay>False</IsAllDay>
  <Recurrence>
    <OriginatingTimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</OriginatingTimeZone>
    <RecurrenceType>0</RecurrenceType>
    <RecurrenceEndDate>9999-12-31T23:59:59</RecurrenceEndDate>
  </Recurrence>
  <IsVariance>False</IsVariance>
  <IsCancelled>False</IsCancelled>
  <OriginalStart>0001-01-01T00:00:00</OriginalStart>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you're selecting:

```
Select sum...<DisplayTitle>.Value
```

The Value property returns a string - so the type of the `summary` variable is `IEnumerable(Of String)`.

You probably just need:

```
For Each item In summary
    sbEventDetail.Append("<h4>" & item & "</h4>")
Next
```

... assuming you don't need any HTML-escaping, mind you.